# regex for matching pattern with key value and delimiter in string

Tags: regex

trying to find the right regex to extract all of the values associated with the pos key in the below:

```
"ip=78351;hmid=hi;hzcs=nl;lang=en;layer=nl;locale=en_us;nzcs=nl;ord=77053733
15;par=nl;plat=wx_droid_phone;plln=hi;pos=top300;rmid=1b97ef2c60b313a5e0c40"
```

would just extract: `top300`

Comment: `(?<=\bpos=)[^;]*`, try to post your attempts.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: @prometheus2305, Are you using PHP as a language? If so, then I can give you an alternative solution in this case.

Comment: As Maroun asked, which language or utility are you using because regex syntax varies widely depending on use, for example, awk/sed regex vs. Perl regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex:

```
\bpos=([^;]*)
```

Explanation:
It matches first the term `pos=`. And second matches everything until the next `;` in a capturing group. This can be referenced later using `$1` or `\1` depending on the language you use.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eG2iT6/2)

Comment: Answering questions that show no effort is not encouraged. As for your regex, non-capturing group is not necessary here.

Comment: @stribizhev: Thanks for the remarks. I adapted my answer and will consider your first point.